# Gatsby pagination problem while verifying that I'm on the first page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination, graphql

I'm trying to build a paginated blog with gatsby and MDX, when I'm on the first page of my blog with the URL /blog and I press the previous page button the verification doesn't work, and instead of staying on the first page it goes to /blog/1 that doesn't exist and throw a 404 error. Here is my template where I try to check if my currentPage is 1 I need to return blog otherwise it needs to return /blog/${currentPage - 1}(and this is working). I have also tried to verify that currentPage - 1 === 1 but the same error appears.

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"
import BlogHomepage from "../components/BlogHomepage"
import Layout from "../components/Layout"
import Pagination from "../components/Pagination"
import ContentCard from "../components/ContentCard"
const allPosts = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  const { currentPage, numPages } = pageContext

  const prevPage = currentPage === 1 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${currentPage - 1}`

  const nextPage =
    currentPage === numPages
      ? `/blog/${currentPage}`
      : `/blog/${currentPage + 1}`

  const posts = data.allMdx.edges

  return (
    <Layout>
      <BlogHomepage>
        {posts.map(post => {
          return (
            <ContentCard
              key={post.node.frontmatter.slug}
              date={post.node.frontmatter.date}
              title={post.node.frontmatter.title}
              excerpt={post.node.frontmatter.excerpt}
              slug={post.node.frontmatter.slug}
            />
          )
        })}
        <Pagination prevPage={prevPage} nextPage={nextPage} />
      </BlogHomepage>
    </Layout>
  )
}

export default allPosts
export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query AllPostsQuery($skip: Int!, $limit: Int!) {
    allMdx(
      sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }
      skip: $skip
      limit: $limit
    ) {
      edges {
        node {
          frontmatter {
            slug
            title
            date
            excerpt
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Also, the pagination button components where I simply pass prevPage and nextPage as props

```
import { Link } from "gatsby"
import React from "react"

 const Pagination = ({ prevPage, nextPage }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <Link
        to={prevPage}
        className="inline-flex text-white bg-blue-500 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-blue-600 rounded text-lg"
      >
        Prev
      </Link>
      <Link
        to={nextPage}
        className="ml-4 inline-flex text-gray-400 bg-gray-800 border-0 py-2 px-6 focus:outline-none hover:bg-gray-700 hover:text-white rounded text-lg"
      >
        Next
      </Link>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

Inside the gatsby-node, I define currentPage as the index of the array pages + 1

```
exports.createPages = async function ({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMdx(sort: { fields: frontmatter___date, order: DESC }) {
        edges {
          node {
            frontmatter {
              slug
            }
            id
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const postPerPage = 3

  const numPages = Math.ceil(data.allMdx.edges.length / postPerPage)

  Array.from({ length: numPages }).forEach((_, i) => {
    actions.createPage({
      path: i === 0 ? `/blog` : `/blog/${i + 1}`,
      component: require.resolve("./src/templates/allPosts.js"),
      context: {
        limit: postPerPage,
        skip: i * postPerPage,
        numPages,
        currentPage: i + 1,
      },
    })
  })
}
```

The rest of the pagination is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone runs into the same error I resolved with this inside the template

```
  const prevPage =
    currentPage - 1 === 0 || currentPage - 1 === 1
      ? `/blog`
      : `/blog/${currentPage - 1}`
```